# why not to send WM_PAINT manually

Tags: c++, winapi, windows-messages, wm-paint

I have read that I should never send `WM_PAINT` manually and should call `InvalidateRect` instead but didn't found anything about why not, however. So why not?

**update** works with `InvalidateRect` but not with `SendMessage(WM_PAINT)`

```
LRESULT CALLBACK window_proc(HWND wnd, UINT msg, WPARAM w_param, LPARAM l_param)
{
  switch (msg)
  {
    case WM_PAINT:
        PAINTSTRUCT ps;
        HDC hdc = BeginPaint(wnd, &ps);

        Polyline(..);

        EndPaint(wnd, &ps);
        return 0;

    case WM_USER:           
        // SendMessage(wnd, WM_PAINT, NULL, NULL);
        // InvalidateRect(wnd, NULL, FALSE);

        return 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: Where did you read it? Whoever wrote that should have included an explanation. Hint: Read what BeginPaint does.

Comment: @RaymondChen it was some time ago.. it was something about that WM_PAINT should be carried by system. today i tried to send WM_PAINT from WM_USER message and it failed. i mean no effect. i'll add my code.

Comment: Getting the code wrong like this is the primary reason you should not send WM_PAINT yourself.  Always favor InvalidateRect(),  call UpdateWindow() after that if you need to the paint to be done immediately.  Which should be quite rare.

Comment: If you never call `InvalidateRect`, then `BeginPaint` says "Oh, the window is still valid. There is no need to paint anything."

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Official docs for [`WM_PAINT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145213.aspx) state that you shouldn't in the very first sentence of the remarks section. Seriously, that should be enough of a reason not to.

As for technical reasons why, I guess this is one of them, taken from [`BeginPaint`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183362.aspx) remarks section:

> The update region is set by the **InvalidateRect** or **InvalidateRgn** function and by the system after sizing, moving, creating, scrolling, or any other operation that affects the client area.

Thus `BeginPaint` might not work correctly if you send `WM_PAINT` manually.

There might be more reasons/surprises.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to trigger an immediate repaint, the correct approach is to either:

1. Use `InvalidateRect()` followed by `UpdateWindow()`.
2. Use `RedrawWindow()`.

Those will trigger a new `WM_PAINT` message to be generated.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have any information about other program's windows uncovering your windows. Only the operating system has this information. So you don't really know all the time when or where your window needs to be repainted.  WM_PAINT and BeginPaint provide this missing information.

Comment: Many (most?) WM_PAINT handlers repaint their entire window without looking at the invalid area to optimize it, so this answer doesn't really explain anything.

Comment: Whether a program uses the invalid area or not, it still doesn't have any way to know when something has been uncovered by other programs and needs repainting. So one has to handle WM_PAINT and one has to call BeginPaint in the handler.

Comment: Nobody is arguing that WM_PAINT needs to be handled or that BeginPaint needs to be called. The question is why sending a WM_PAINT to yourself doesn't work, even though it ends up in the same handler code. This answer does not address this vital question.

Comment: @MarkRansom All the controls from the common controls library only redraw the invalidated area. Since most applications rely on those, most applications also get this behaviour for free. Many *custom* WM_PAINT handlers might do this wrong, but those are comparatively rare.

Answer (score 1):

Because `WM_PAINT` is not a real message.

Think of it like each window has a structure storing an "invalid region", that is, "this part of the window on the screen is not up to date anymore and need to be repainted".

That invalid region is modified by the window manager itself (window is resized, uncovered, etc ), or by calls to `InvalidateRect`, `ValidateRect`, `EndPaint` and such.

Now, here is a crude mock-up of how `GetMessage` handles this :

```
... GetMessage(MSG* msg, ...)
{
  while(true) {
    if(ThereIsAnyMessageInTheMessageQueue()) {
      *msg = GetFirstMessageOfTheMessageQueue();
      return ...;
    } else if(TheInvalidRegionIsNotEmpty()) {
      *msg = CreateWMPaintMessage();
      return ...;
    } else {
      WaitUntilSomethingHappend();
    }
  }
}
```

tl;dr:  `WM_PAINT` is meant to be received, not sent.